# Base64 encoded string for image in java is not valid in php

Tags: java, php, android, encoding

I have seen many examples and still not able to get my work done. 
I'm using below code for encoding my image into Base64 string

```
public static String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    Log.v(Constant.TAG,"Encoded String"+encodedImage);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

when I post this `encodedImage` to my web server where PHP is running, it doesn't decode back to the image
I tested it using below PHP code

```
if ( base64_encode(base64_decode($image, true)) === $image){
    echo '$data is valid';
} else {
        echo '$data is NOT valid';
}
```

where the $image has encoded string.

Below are two strange things.

1. Encoded string in java is decodable in java, I can decode it back and get the bitmap and successfully able to display it using image view
2. "==" sign is not coming to the end of the encoded string.

Please tell me what exactly is going wrong?

Here is base64 code:
http://pixyfi.kgcorner.com/uploads/test.txt

Below is code for uploading image

```
public static String makePostRequest(String url,String params)
{
    String response="";
    try {
        URL restURL= new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)restURL.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os= connection.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter writer= new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8");
        writer.write(params);
        writer.flush();
        InputStream is=new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        response=convertStreamToString(is);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(Constant.TAG,e.getMessage(),e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(Constant.TAG,e.getMessage(),e);
    }
    return response;
}
```

param is query string containing all parameters that i need to send to server. 
image=&details=

How i'm getting it on php side

```
$image=$_POST['image'];
```

How do i validate it

```
if ( base64_encode(base64_decode($image, true)) === $image){
    echo "valid";
} else {
        echo "NOT valid";
}
```

Output coming is Not Valid.

Comment: can you post your both Base64 string?

Comment: I have only one base64 string and will post by evening

Comment: In Base64 are 64 "digits" `A-z0-9/+` and hence every char has a payload of 6 bits. Groups of 4 chars have a payload of 3 bytes. Base64 implementations often have an option to add padding signs `=` to fill the last group of 4 chars/3 bytes. Look in the used API, or pad yourself. Should PHP require those.

Comment: try `Base64.DEFAULT`?
`String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(raw, Base64.DEFAULT);` works just fine in my application.

Comment: Tried that too, still not working

Comment: @KumarGaurav how you send the data from android to PHP file?

Comment: Kindly check updated content

Comment: Any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to solve.
I Actually found that there is no issue with java and actually with php. 
Below is final code for decoding the image in php

```
$image = str_replace(' ','+',$image); //replacing ' ' with '+' 
if ( base64_encode(base64_decode($image, true)) === $image){
    echo '$data is valid';
} else {
        echo '$data is NOT valid';
}
```